# this keyword side-effect in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular directive and it is used in one of the components. The problem is when I pass a method of the component as an argument for directive and then launch in the directive, the `this` keyword refers to something other than the component.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[listenTo]"
})
export class ListenToDirective {
  @Input('listenTo') listenerConfiguration: {event: string, listener: (event?: Event) => any, global?: boolean }[];
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private userInputService: UserInputService)
  {}

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (const setup of this.listenerConfiguration) {
      if (setup.global) {
        this.subscriptions.push(
          this.userInputService.subscribe(setup.event).subscribe(setup.listener)
        );
      } else this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, setup.event, setup.listener);
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    for (const sub of this.subscriptions) {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

listen-to.directive.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'color-hue',
  templateUrl: './color-hue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./color-hue.component.scss']
})
export class ColorHueComponent {

  @Output('hue') hueOutput = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @ViewChild('HueContainer') hueContainer: ElementRef<Element>;

  isMoving = false;
  pickerPosition = 0;
  pickerColorHue = 0;

  onContainerMouseDown() {
    console.log("hello");
    this.isMoving = true;
  }

  onContainerMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.isMoving) {
      console.log(event.clientY);
      const box = this.hueContainer.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const beginY = box.y;
      const mouseY = event.clientY;
      this.pickerPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(box.height, mouseY - beginY));
      this.hueOutput.emit(this.pickerColorHue = Math.min(this.pickerPosition / box.height, 0.999) * 360);
    }
  }
}
```

color-hue.component.ts

```
<div class="hue">
  <div class="hue-pointer-container" #HueContainer
       [listenTo]=
         "[
            { event: 'mousemove', listener: onContainerMouseMove, global: true }
         ]"
    >
    <
  </div>
</div>
```

color-hue.component.html

so in directive, this.isMoving is undefined. How should I use method of component in the derictive properly

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in a arrow function, so you can use `this`.

> In classic function expressions, the this keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which the function is called. Whereas arrow functions use the value of this in their lexical scope. This leads to very different behaviour.

[Read this](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e)

Doing this should work:

```
onContainerMouseMove() {
    return (event: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log(this.isMoving);
      if (this.isMoving) {
        console.log(event.clientY);
        const box = this.hueContainer.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const beginY = box.y;
        const mouseY = event.clientY;
        this.pickerPosition = Math.max(
          0,
          Math.min(box.height, mouseY - beginY)
        );
        this.hueOutput.emit(
          (this.pickerColorHue =
            Math.min(this.pickerPosition / box.height, 0.999) * 360)
        );
      }
    };
  }
```

```html
<div class="hue">
  <div class="hue-pointer-container" #HueContainer [listenTo]="[
            { event: 'mousemove', listener: onContainerMouseMove(), global: true }
         ]">
  </div>
</div>
```